# Using Make $(dir) or $(notdir) on a path with spaces

Tags: makefile, path, quoting

I'm using code similar to the following in a Makefile:

```
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
path_escape = $(subst $(space),\$(space),$(1))

TOP=$(call path_escape,$(abspath .))
TARGET=$(TOP)/foo

$(info TOP='$(TOP)')
$(info TARGET='$(TARGET)')

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):
    touch '$(notdir $@)'

.PHONY: $(TARGET)
```

If I use this in a directory with no spaces, say `space-test`, it works fine:

```
$ make
TOP='/tmp/space-test'
TARGET='/tmp/space-test/foo'
touch 'foo'
```

However, if I use it in a directory with spaces, say `space test`, then `$(notdir)` does the wrong thing:

```
TOP='/tmp/space\ test'
TARGET='/tmp/space\ test/foo'
touch 'space foo'
```

What's happening here is that `$(notdir)` interprets `/tmp/space test/foo` as *two* paths and returns the "file part" of *both* (i.e., `space` and `foo`). The weird part of this is that `TARGET` is properly escaped; somehow, inside the rule or inside `$(notdir)`, the backslash escapes are being ignored.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$(notdir)` function in GNU Make takes a list of arguments, separated by spaces.  Some functions support escaping spaces with `\\`, but `$(notdir)` is not one of them.

This should work:

```
s? = $(subst $(empty) ,?,$1)
?s = $(subst ?, ,$1)
notdirx = $(call ?s,$(notdir $(call s?,$1)))

$(TARGET):
    touch '$(call notdirx,$@)'
```

This defines a "space-safe" version of `notdir` called `notdirx`.  It's quite simple: `s?` first turns all spaces to question marks (hoping that they cannot be present in file names), and `?s` converts back.  In between we can safely call the original `notdir` function.

For an excellent summary on GNU Make and spaces in file names, see [GNU Make meets file names with spaces in them](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/7859-gnu-make-meets-file-names-with-spaces-in-them).

Comment: Thanks, Ville. It's pretty ridiculous that there's no way to escape inputs to $(notdir) except via this hack (or so it seems).

Comment: Yeah.  GNU Make could really use an optionally enabled (backwards incompatible) version 2 of the language and standard functions.  Or maybe it's best to just use, say, SCons or something with a real programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Unix shell, you could shell out:

```
notdirx = $(shell basename '$1')
dirx = $(shell dirname '$1')
```

A similar strategy could apply to other functions. Just remember the quote marks around the variable that contains the whitespace-infected text that you want to treat as a single argument. This will also protect you from other special characters (except for quote marks!). Here's an example to double-backslash escape any spaces in the result of a wildcard glob:

```
$(shell ls -1 '*.foo' | sed 's/ /\\\\ /g')
```

Windows is putting parentheses in directory names now, too: `C:\Program Files (x86)\` It's not yet clear to me what are the implications of this when using `make`.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a shot in the dark:

```
TOP='"/home/chris/src/tests/make/space test"'
```

Comment: Gary, I don't hate you, I am full of love. Don't take down-votes personally, they just signal whether an answer is correct and/or helpful. In this case, no, this does not work.

Comment: We aren't downvoting **you**, we're downvoting your **answer**. Don't feel bad about that.