# loopback odbc_bindings.node Image not found

Tags: loopback, dashdb

I'm trying to set up a DashDB datasource on a Loopback project.

I am running node -v 6.10.1 & npm -v 3.10.10

I get the following error when trying to initialize a new Dashdb datasource:

```js
npm ERR! argv "/Users/bannastre/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/node" "/Users/bannastre/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/npm" "install" "loopback-connector-dashdb@^1.0.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ibm_db@1.0.2 install: `node installer/driverInstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ibm_db@1.0.2 install script 'node installer/driverInstall.js'.
```

So I try setting the loopback connector using `npm install loopback-connector-dashdb --save`, which runs ok.

When I try and run the app I get an error. It looks like this beause of the `odbc_bindings.node` file or `libdb2.dylib`.

When I run `node .` the following error is thrown:

```js
Error: dlopen(../projects/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node, 1): Library not loaded: ../projects/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
  Referenced from: ../projects/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node
  Reason: image not found
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (../projects/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (../projects/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js:27:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Am I missing a package?

Comment: I think you need install: loopback-connector-dashdb@^1.0.0

Comment: Thanks but this fails because the package loopback-connector-dashdb is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a native node issue. Could you try running the following command from your app:

```
npm cache clean && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's to do with having a space in the path (It's on a ~/Google Drive/projects path) - The ibm_db package Release/Makefile can't handle that

There's an issue raised here:
[Using Make $(dir) or $(notdir) on a path with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189781/using-make-dir-or-notdir-on-a-path-with-spaces)